# How to access the XmlElementAttribute order

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl

I reference a web service, which is defined in a WSDL file. The WSDL file uses sequences, which define a certain order of the elements. In my reference.cs file, this order is correctly adopted such as

```
public class name {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string firstname {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

How can I access the order value of member firstname in class name?

---

Exemplary WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://webaddress.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="WSDLService" targetNamespace="http://webaddress.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://webaddress.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webaddress.com/" version="1.0">
            <xs:complexType name="name">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Do you need to use Serialization? Can you parse instead using Xml Linq?

Comment: Well, I create an instance `myName` of class `name`, which has a member `myName.firstname`. I need to know the order of that member. Matching each member with its occurrence in a parsed XML file is cumbersome. If that is the only solution, I know how to do that.

Comment: Can you post a sample of Xml so I understand the issue better?  I usually like using a dictionary so the key of the dictionary would be the name and the value is the List<XElement>.

Comment: I added an exemplary WSDL file. That file is automatically parsed into the C# file `reference.cs`, which contains all the class definitions that can be accessed. The `sequence` element causes the `XmlElementAttribute` `order` = 0 for firstname and 1 for lastname. So actually, order = 0 and order = 1 is not contained in the WSDL file.

Answer (score 0):

I used the xsd.exe utility to generate classes. I had to modify the xsd because it failed the validation.  The used code below to generate an xml file and then read it back in.

Here is the schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://webaddress.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webaddress.com/" version="1.0">
  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            name Name = new name()
            {
                firstname = "John",
                lastname = "Smith"
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME,settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(name));
            serializer.Serialize(writer,Name);

            writer.Close();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            name readName = (name)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://webaddress.com/")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://webaddress.com/", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class name
    {

        private string firstnameField;

        private string lastnameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string firstname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.firstnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.firstnameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string lastname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lastnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lastnameField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. But I don't see where I can retrieve information about the values of the `order` attribute. What I need is a function that returns a value of zero either for the object `firstname` or for the string `"firstname"` and a value of one for `lastname`.

Comment: Why do you care?  You can get the element using the attribute.  If you really need the index you wold need to use a custom serialization method.